# Terraform - "An argument named is not expected here" when using maps

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm creating a simple terraform module, like this one

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "terraform_state" {
  bucket = var.bucket

  lifecycle_rule = var.s3_lifecycle

  versioning {
    enabled = true
    mfa_delete = false
  }

  server_side_encryption_configuration = var.s3_server_side_encryption_configuration

  policy = var.s3_policy

  tags = var.s3_tags

  force_destroy = var.s3_force_destroy

  logging = var.s3_logging
}
```

All variables are defined as maps, apart from the bucket name.

When I try to call the module like this

```
module "backend" {
    source = "../"

    bucket = "terraform_state_test_${random_id.random_bucket_id.hex}"

    s3_lifecycle = {
      prevent_destroy = false
    }

    s3_force_destroy = false

    s3_tags = {
        TerraformManaged = "true"
        env = "test"
    }

    s3_server_side_encryption_configuration = {
      rule = {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default = {
        sse_algorithm = "AES256"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have several error in all maps (aside from the "tags") like this

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on ../main.tf line 11, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "terraform_state":
  11:   server_side_encryption_configuration = var.s3_server_side_encryption_configuration

An argument named "server_side_encryption_configuration" is not expected here.
Did you mean to define a block of type "server_side_encryption_configuration"?
```

I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong...can someone help me?

Thanks,

Comment: The `server_side_encryption_configuration` expects something like `server_side_encryption_configuration { ... }` similar to the `versioning`. It is not a map.

Comment: @luk2302 in this case...what is that variable? The docs are not mentioning the type...And how can I pass the variable?

Comment: It does not have a type, it is a block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not correct as per the docs.

> server_side_encryption_configuration = var.s3_server_side_encryption_configuration

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "mybucket" {
  bucket = "mybucket"

  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        kms_master_key_id = aws_kms_key.mykey.arn
        sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Enable Default Server Side Encryption](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket#enable-default-server-side-encryption)

[here](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-s3-bucket/blob/master/main.tf#L183) is a neat example.

```
# Max 1 block - server_side_encryption_configuration
dynamic "server_side_encryption_configuration" {
for_each = length(keys(var.server_side_encryption_configuration)) == 0 ? [] : [var.server_side_encryption_configuration]

content {

    dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = length(keys(lookup(server_side_encryption_configuration.value, "rule", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [lookup(server_side_encryption_configuration.value, "rule", {})]

    content {

        dynamic "apply_server_side_encryption_by_default" {
        for_each = length(keys(lookup(rule.value, "apply_server_side_encryption_by_default", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [
        lookup(rule.value, "apply_server_side_encryption_by_default", {})]

        content {
            sse_algorithm     = apply_server_side_encryption_by_default.value.sse_algorithm
            kms_master_key_id = lookup(apply_server_side_encryption_by_default.value, "kms_master_key_id", null)
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
}
```

Depending on your needs you can customize the module's example.

Comment: So I cannot create a module for that resource?

Comment: @LucaB yes you can.

Comment: Now I saw your edit answer... ok I will try that way, thanks :)

Comment: @LucaB Note that the last snippet *may* be overkill in your usecase, depends on how complex the `server_side_encryption_configuration` will get in your case.

Comment: @luk2302 I added a mention of that already in the answer, <Depending on your needs you can customize the module's example.> :) .  The code I shared was just an example to nudge him in the correct direction and terraform resource to use for such case.